# Почему sizeof выводит 12 байтов в следующем массиве строк ? Язык Си

Tags: c, массивы, строки, указатели, sizeof

Почему sizeof выводит 12 байтов в следующем массиве строк ? Язык Си.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main (void)
{   
   const char* states[] = {"Moscow", "New-York" ,"Kiev"};
   printf("\r\n%zu", sizeof (states));
   return;
}
```

Comment: Потому что его размер 12 байтов

Comment: Потому что это массив из 3 указателей, каждый размером по 4 байта (32-разрядная программа). Итого - 12...

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function

Comment: Понятно ,что массив содержит 3 указателя. Но почему каждый весит 4 байта ? Тип char занимает ведь 1 байт.